# MySQL delete returning before complete in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

Summary: It appears that my 'delete' statement returns before it is finished deleting. How can wait until it is done?

Long version: I have a PHP script running against an innoDB MySQL table that deletes a set of records from the database. Something like:

`delete from sections where term = '15/FA'`

I then follow up with a set of insert statements.

The problem is, my code will be partially into inserting my new records when the prior delete finishes and clears out some of the new records I inserted. That's bad.

If I call 'sleep()' for a second after calling the delete everything runs fine. Obviously that's not a proper or reliable solution, but it does show there is a timing issue.

There may be more, less, or different records than the records I just deleted. Using 'update' instead of insert isn't going to work.

I use the auto-increment id I get back from the insert to insert more records into a child tables. So it isn't practical to do the whole set of deletes and inserts in one long script. (Or if it is, I don't know how.)

So is there some way to know when the 'delete' function is done? Or do I need to give up and switch to a real database?

Comment: Did you try using a Transaction in MySQL?

Comment: post some code so we can actually help

Comment: Some code could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have large number of rows in the table so the query does take a while. You could try adding an index on the column you want to filter in the delete query.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @Jay Thanks. I will take care now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE` will *not* return before deleting the rows.  Please describe, in detail, the steps that made you think that happened.

You have the InnoDB tag, so I assume you are using InnoDB?  Is more than one connection involved?  Is `term` indexed?  Are you using BEGIN...COMMIT?  Did a transaction get ROLLBACK'd?

If all of these occur, it could *appear* that something is amiss:

- You have two separate connections -- one with the DELETE.
- The transaction_isolation_mode is `READ_UNCOMMITTED` or something like that.
- The second connection starts looking for the record before the `DELETE` is `COMMITted`.
- You fail to check for errors.